# FFTW3: Query the SIMD-alignment

Tags: fftw

According to the docs [SIMD alignment and fftw_malloc](https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/SIMD-alignment-and-fftw_005fmalloc.html)

> the arrays of complex (or real) data passed to FFTW must be specially aligned in memory (typically 16-byte aligned)[...]
>
> In order to guarantee proper alignment for SIMD [...] we recommend allocating your transform data with fftw_malloc and de-allocating it with fftw_free.

Now when passing windows of a continous buffer into FFTW, how can I tell whether or not they'll be aligned? More specifically: If I use fftw_malloc to allocate a buffer for FFTW, at what offsets may I window this buffer to keep the alignment requirements?

It says the alignment is "typically" 16-byte but how can I tell for sure?

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems that the alignment is not exported but can take the values 16, 32 and 64 https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/blob/master/kernel/ifftw.h#L133C5-L133C14 so I can at least be guaranteed to stay aligned if my offsets divide by 64.